# r dygraph and shiny modules

Tags: r, shiny, dygraphs

I am starting to use shiny modules for my UI and server. I have a specific problem with the display of the dygraph legend.

Before using shiny modules I could just display the graph and the legend in my UI. It stopped working once I used the modules. Could it be that the legend of dygraph is not an reactive output?

**No shiny moudles (works)**

...

```
tabPanel("Plot",dygraphOutput("plot1"),

    textOutput("legendDivID"))
...
```

The dygraph server code:

```
output$plot1 <- renderDygraph({

    dygraph(dfplot())%>% 
    dyLegend(labelsDiv = "legendDivID", labelsSeparateLines = T)%>% 
    dyRangeSelector()
  })
```

**Now I build my shiny modules**

```
StockUI<-function(id, label= "aaa"){
  ns <- NS(id)#Named space
...
tabPanel("Plot",dygraphOutput(ns("plot1")),
                             textOutput(ns("legendDivID"))}

Stock <- function(input,output,session){
...
output$plot1 <- renderDygraph({dygraph(foo())%>% 
      dyLegend(labelsDiv = "legendDivID", labelsSeparateLines = T)%>% 
      dyRangeSelector()
  }) 
}
```

But the Legend is no longer displayed, it works fine outside the shiny modules.

Answer (score 1):

Your `legendDivId` in the UI is wrapped inside `ns`, so it should be wrapped inside `ns` in the server, too. `ns` in the server can be assessed through `server$ns`. This should work:

```
output$plot1 <- renderDygraph({dygraph(foo())%>% 
      dyLegend(labelsDiv = session$ns("legendDivID"), labelsSeparateLines = T)%>% 
      dyRangeSelector()
  })
```